# How to prefill text without user´s possibility of deleting it

Tags: php, html, textarea

is there any way to prefill textarea with link of page that user is trying to share but so that he can´t delete it. I am talking about sharing form via email.
The form is obviously done in php.

Edit:

I used the field Edit Summary but I don´t see it anywhere so it may be here twice I can be blind :D

The onlyread function is not what I´ve wanted. User is allowed to write into textarea but the part of the text hasn´t be touchable. As junkfoodjunkie said it seems like the only way to do it. But still posting some advices if you see the whole code may change it.

Comment: Can you show your form?

Comment: you could add the `disabled="disabled"` attribute to the field, but ultimately you have no control over any client-side information.

Answer (score 1):

most inputs can use `readonly="readonly"` to prevent predefined values from being edited.

```
<textarea name="verbage" readonly=readonly cols="5" rows="9">
Can't touch this
</textarea>

<input type="text" name='moreverbage" readonly=readonly value="NO EDITING ALLOWED">
```

Comment: thanks for accepting my answer. I should mention, as junkfoodjunkie correctly points out, this only prevents the typical viewer from changing the values, however, for a geek, it's trivial to roll your own form and post whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If the mail sending is done via PHP, just have that default text be part of the server-side send-mail script, and put it in if the text in the message / textarea doesn't contain the default text. You cannot trust client side solutions, and all of the solutions mentioned above is removed by a simple code-editor (Firebug, for instance), before clicking `submit`.

Check the content in the mail-sending script, and if the default text isn't there, either replace or add/prepend the text you want.